# Why does setting "that probability to zero means a single shot to the engine is guaranteed to bring the plane down"?

Tags: probability

The author sets to zero $\color{limegreen}{\text{the
probability that a plane that takes a hit to the engine manages to stay in the air}}$. Let's call this $p$.

But how does $p = 0$ imply anything about $\color{red}{\text{"planes coming back with bullet holes all over the wings, the fuselage, the nose"}}$? These probabilities feel unrelated to me, because the author defined $p$ for hits to merely the engine, not these other aircraft parts?

> The armor, said Wald, doesn’t go where the bullet holes are. It goes where  the bullet holes *aren’t*: on the engines.
>       Wald’s insight was simply to ask: where are the missing holes? The ones
> that would have been all over the engine casing, if the damage had been spread
> equally all over the plane? Wald was pretty sure he knew. The missing bullet
> holes were on the missing planes. The reason planes were coming back with
> fewer hits to the engine is that planes that got hit in the engine weren’t coming
> back. Whereas the large number of planes returning to base with a thoroughly
> Swiss-cheesed fuselage is pretty strong evidence that hits to the fuselage can
> (and therefore should) be tolerated. If you go the recovery room at the
> hospital, you’ll see a lot more people with bullet holes in their legs than
> people with bullet holes in their chests. But that’s not because people don’t
> get shot in the chest; it’s because the people who get shot in the chest don’t
> recover.
>        Here’s an old mathematician’s trick that makes the picture perfectly clear:
> *set some variables to zero*. In this case, the variable to tweak is $\color{limegreen}{\text{the
> probability that a plane that takes a hit to the engine manages to stay in the air}}$. **Setting that probability to zero means a single shot to the engine is guaranteed
> to bring the plane down. [Emphasis mine]** What would the data look like then? You’d have
> $\color{red}{\text{planes coming back with bullet holes all over the wings, the fuselage, the nose}}$
> —but none at all on the engine. The military analyst has two options for
> explaining this: either the German bullets just happen to hit every part of the
> plane but one, or the engine is a point of total vulnerability. Both stories
> explain the data, but the latter makes a lot more sense. The armor goes where
> the bullet holes aren’t.
>       Wald’s recommendations were quickly put into effect, and were still
> being used by the navy and the air force through the wars in Korea and
> Vietnam. I can’t tell you exactly how many American planes they saved,
> though the data-slinging descendants of the SRG inside today’s military no
> doubt have a pretty good idea. One thing the American defense establishment
> has traditionally understood very well is that countries don’t win wars just by
> being braver than the other side, or freer, or slightly preferred by God. The
> winners are usually the guys who get 5% fewer of their planes shot down, or
> use 5% less fuel, or get 5% more nutrition into their infantry at 95% of the
> cost. That’s not the stuff war movies are made of, but it’s the stuff wars are
> made of. And there’s math every step of the way.

Ellenberg, *How Not to Be Wrong: The Power of Mathematical Thinking* (2014), p 7.

Comment: What is the concern here? You should share your thoughts.

Comment: Suppose that if a plane is hit in the engine, there is some probability $p$ that it stays in the air. The paragraph is saying that if $p=0$, then hitting a plane's engine will bring the plane down.

Comment: if a plane comes back, it has come back through the air; it has managed to stay in the air.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta I edited my post. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is clear from the context, planes are very likely to get hit. And if it's impossible to make it back when you're hit to the engine, the planes that do make it back despite being hit must have been hit at *other* places than the engine.